# Will a threading event be automatically closed after program exit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events

If I create and Event(threading), and it's never received, so that it's always in signaled state.
And IMHO, this signaled event exists somewhere in the OS.
So, I'm guessing "is it that this signaled event will always be there even after the program that created it has exited?"

Comment: No, when the program exists, each and every handle it creates will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, Roth. If you can put your answer to a post, then I can pick it as the answer and close my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the C and C++ standards don't actually go into "what happens after the program exits". It is up to the OS [or whatever it may be that "runs" the code] to deal with that. Most OS's will clean up all "handles" and other "per process runtime objects an resources" that the program creates. This is particularly important for processes that crash, since we could technically cause the entire system to go down by crashing out sufficiently many times (all memory being used, or excessively large number of files, events or other resources).